# Clicking title of Documentation revision opens edit page with no way to close the editor

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-editor

After clicking the title of a Documentation revision ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/30736?draftId=27619)) I'm taken to a page that shows the editor with no obvious way to close it.

> [image]

Comment: Yes, I would expect this link to send to the topic. Very frustrating, but (until it's fixed) you can click the "this topic" link from the revision page, on the line of tabs related to the tag, to avoid falling in this limbo.

Comment: The problem here isn't necessarily the fast that it's sending me to the edit page, it's that the buttons that'd normally close the editor/save your changes are missing and the page is useless as a result.